# Vue 3/Typescript/vscode async submit handlers type error

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vuejs3

I have a `form` in a Vue 3 component and I'm calling an async submit handler:

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="handleLogin">
    <!-- inputs etc -->
  </form>
<template>
<script setup lang="ts">

// unrelated code...

const handleLogin = async (event: Event) => {
  try {
    await login({ ...form.value });
    resetForm();
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error(error.error_description || error.message);
  }
  return event
};
</script>
```

In vscode the `@submit` is being highlighted with this typescript error:

```
Type '(event: Event) => Promise<Event>' is not assignable to type 'Event'.ts(2322)
__VLS_types.ts(108, 56): The expected type comes from property 'submit' which is declared here on type 'EventObject<undefined, "submit", {}, Event | undefined>'
```

The error makes sense, `handleLogin` returns a `Promise<Event>` and `submit` expects an `Event`.

I just don't know how to resolve (pun intended) this error. How should I invoke an async handler?

Comment: Actually, I don't get that error on my project. So maybe there are some special configs on your project that caused the error

Comment: I don't get the error either. Is there a reason why you're returning a promise in the first place?

Comment: @NikolaGava because I need to await the async login and, if successful, after that reset the login form. There are actually a couple more async methods being called in the actual code.

Comment: @Duannx Thanks, I'll investigate my configs to see what might be causing it.

Comment: I ment to ask why are you returning event from the handleLogin method? Your method doesn't need to return anything.

Comment: @NikolaGava just to make the signature closer to what is apparently expected by that Typescript message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I restarted vscode I saw there was a problem listed in the editor footer. Clicking on it showed:

[image: Error description linking to the volar issue linked above]

As shown in the image this was an issue with the Volar VSCode plugin: https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/1985

Upgrading `@types/node` to `18.11.1` or later would solve it.

Now that I'm confident this isn't an error in my code I will just ignore this error until an underlying Vue ticket is merged.

So I can revert my handler to not using the event:

```
const handleLogin = async () => {
  try {
    await login({ ...form.value });
    resetForm();
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error(error.error_description || error.message);
  }
};
```